# Issues Flashing STM32F401CC with CubeProgrammer DFU

Tags: arduino, stm32, arduino-ide, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I'm trying to do a DFU program upload via Arduino for an STM32F401CC. I'm using CubeProgrammer to upload the compiled bin and verify the contents of the STM32's flash is being written starting at 0x8 -- it's all there. I'm using a jumper to pull B0 high and am verifying it shows as STM32 BOOTLOADER in the device manager, then I'm disconnecting it. Everything shows that the program is upload correctly, but my program isn't actually running (make onboard PC13 LED blink). I'm using a board I got off amazon but verified the STM32F401CC is genuine. Is there something I'm missing? I'm coming over to ARM after years of using the ESP32.

Comment: How is this the most miserable way of programming it? I figured DFU would be easier than a debug probe? I have a FTDI cable, is there a serial interface I can use to program it?

Comment: Of course, millions of developers are using debug probes because they do not know that DFU is more convenient :)

Comment: Ok... I'll order one lol. In the meantime though, is there a way to get DFU working?

Answer (score 0):

I had couple bought and both the same problem,as yours, supposingly they were fake ones and wrong batch,so port in arduino ide wasnt recognized and the same issue as above in stmcubeprogrammer. It was stm32401ccu6 gh27a batch 103, only way was flash with full erase (manually didnt work only automatically in stm32cubeprogrammer ) possible but after each download code to mcu in arduino IDE i couldnt download any more sketches on it and had to upload new firmware / bootloader again and it didnt finish i had to press stop button in stmcube programmer during burning bootloader so trash, cheap peace of all kind of problems, i had to read the chineese documentation From WeAct on git because those with HID bootloader was just crap bad english , so more timre carefully didnt make even sense, so finally figure out how to flash finally bougt same chip 411 and it worked but Arduino ide sketch led didnt  Blink another piece of cheap clone, 411ceu6 batch 106, at least could upload firmware sucesfully in stm32programmer but Arduino sketches didnt work , i had one 411 already from different manufacturere and didnt have these issues, and next time i will give it last try with WeAct orig chineese manufacturer which makes suposedly only original nonfake Stm32f411ce ver 3.0 product on aliexpress and they sell since 2022 411ceu6 batch 014 allegedly its only one which should not give all kinds of issues As they state on their git. Had anyone same problem solved to finally blinking led in arduino ide? It even didnt switch the build in on PC13 but i could measure 3,1V on that pin to ground, and everytime i burn the orig Or hid bootloader The led fades in and out, its a mystery to me really whats going wrong, someone on forums wrote issues with timer, it has to be sth with arduino ide 1.8.19 or stmduino , then noticed in board manager i have../raw/master/package_stmicroelectronics_index.json in preferences arduino ide and stated there as depreciated so i there was srated i shall be using raw/main/package_stmicroelectronics_index.json Oh my thing So i changed the word master into main and typed in Board manager STM32 MCU based boards and installed actual version 2.2.So instead of chaos just be patient and check literally everything, arduno could pop up message that mcu package depreciated but didnt ;) oh my...suddenly surprice, i need check yet if all worked and i just underwent wrong rumors, so no, it has 1,20V on PC13 diode doesnt blink with blink sketch only after bootloader upload fading, i hate such a job and bought 3 and all of them the same. Doesnt work eiter Led_buildin nor pc13, It was swg method, if i set led high and upload via serial i measure 1,9v and if I set led low i measure 1,3 v with Vin 5V and voltage drop ,5v results in 4,45v complete rambazamba , so i start tombelieve these boards are fake anyone similar or same experience?

Comment: Hi @Pete and welcome to SO. Can you please improve your answer by adding punctuation, text formatting etc.? The value of information you are willing to share can be much higher if others can read it clearly. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Weact Blacpill board used ARMS-core STM32F411CEU6
This 40 pin mini board included custom bootloader called "WeACt Studio HID Bootloader" at from 0x08000000 to 0x08003FFF (4K bytes)

If you will using custome "WeAct Studio HID bootloader" for upload, You have to make Arduino sketch object (Arduino IDE > Menu > Sketch > Export copiled binary) upload to 0x08004000 by sperate software of WeAct_HID_FW_Bootloader upload tool.

But, If your blackpill lost "WeAct Studio HID Bootloader under version 2.11",
or another custome bootloader, you have to according upload by custom bootloader.

Lastly, press boot0 key > press reset key > release reset key > release boot=0 key,
Your blackpill mini board will be STM standard DFU mode,
If you will use DFU mode, your bootloader will erase custome bootloader all area and burn to start from 0x08000000 to 0x08003FFF

If you can not use DFU software (Normally almost DFU mode of STM32F411CEU6 will unknown USB device(Failure when installing device driver) in "Device Manager".

Finally you want to burn new bootloader, You have to use 4 wire SWD connect to STLINK Debug dongle.